# Inkscape 0.48: Rearrange paths

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to rearrange paths into others in Inkscape 0.48 (Ubuntu).
I've just created a basic map. 
[image: map]

The paths I drew are quite random and don't represent anything, for example the border of each continent is one path. Basically what I'm trying to do is to make each country of the map a single path (and thus how to duplicate the line that are part of several coutries ?). I tried several tools in Inkscape, so far I didn't achieve what I want.
How should I do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to fill each country with the [paint bucket tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Bucket.html)? It should do the trick.

Comment: You're welcome! Now you can add by yourself an answer and mark this question as solved ;-)